# send email with 1 or more attachments

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will send up to 4 different attachments. The script will always send at least 1 attachment.

```
    Send-MailMessage -to $EmailTo -Body $Body -Subject "$TodayDate Report" -Attachments $UsersResultFileName,$NumbersTableFilename -From 'r-@doman.com' -SmtpServer 'server' -port '25' -BodyAsHtml -ErrorAction Stop
```

Each variable in attachments can lead to a path and a file name.

The issue I am having is sometimes a variable is empty or null. When that happens the `send-mail` fails with an error saying an attachment is null and the error is not wrong.

I know I can `if` my way to all the combinations but there has to be another way?

Comment: `$attachments = $a, $b, $c, $d | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }` but I don't see what's wrong with the `if` conditions I think that's fine too

Comment: The problem was its a lot of ```if``` combos. I will try your idea.

Comment: Alternative; `$Attachments = $vars | Where-Object{ $_ -is [Object] -and (Test-Path $_) }` Should probably ensure the file exists too.

Comment: very interesting. thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Santiagos works, but I think the following is more pretty

`Send-MailMessage -to $EmailTo -Body $Body -Subject "$TodayDate Report" -Attachments ($UsersResultFileName,$NumbersTableFilename -ne $null) -From 'r-@doman.com' -SmtpServer 'server' -port '25' -BodyAsHtml -ErrorAction Stop`

Apparently boolean expressions work as filters with arrays

Comment: ^ This works but it is insane that it does